# Reference Request: Basic Properties of Function Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Is there any resource (book, article,...) that presents all the basic function spaces (Metrizable, Normed, Banach, Sobolev, Hilbert, $L^p$, C[a,b], etc.) together with their properties (completeness, separability, reflexivity, compactness, and other special properties maybe...,etc) and diagrams with arrows (which space is also other space, e.g., Normed Space is also a Metrizable space)?

I find it difficult to search anytime properties of these spaces...

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you are currently learning about these spaces? If so, it's probably quite a useful exercise to construct such a list yourself.